# Outlook 365 - Sending Mail To, CC, CCC boxes to big

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Hi there I've a case here that a user complain about is Outlook Mail Windows. the Section where to set the recipient, CC et CCC, .... are bigger then normal, and I can't find any option to change this to the normal layout. Anyone have a clue?

Normal new mail windows:

### [image: Normal new mail windows]

With Big recipient, To, CC boxes
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the detailed version of Office 365?

Office 365 has released a new feature: new look of ribbon. According to the Release notes, this feature first appears on version 1809 to try out new user experiences before they’re released.

You can check if you've seen an option "Coming Soon" in the upper right corner of Outlook client. If yes, you can turn off this option. If not, I'm afraid we cannot revert to the old look. Update of this ribbon UI aims to improve user experience.

Reference: [Outlook redesign revealed, coming soon](https://content.sentrian.com.au/blog/outlook-redesign-revealed-coming-soon)

[Outlook 365 and coming soon button](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6b0c5409-0976-4d2a-a5ed-f188cc82f06d/outlook-365-and-coming-soon-button?forum=outlook)